# How to fix in package not installed issue while upgrading angular project?

Tags: angular

I want to upgrade my angular project so I'm using the below command to achieve this,

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.3
```

But I'm getting below error after running this command.

```
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 8 dependencies.
Package is not installed.
```

Can you please suggest me an idea to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `--to` option. So it'll be

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.3 --to=UPDATE_VERSION
```